# ansible filter to map array and put in json template

Tags: python, ansible, jinja2, ansible-filter

I have an array variable as following

```
registries:
- type: primary
  host: r1.example.com
- type: secondary
  host: r2.example.com
```

I want to render the host attribute only from each array item inside a `json.j2` template. 
I tried the following in the template :

```
{ 
  "insecure-registries": {{ registries | map(attribute='host') | to_json }}
}
```

Unfortunately , it does not work but it throw this error while running the playbook :

> AnsibleError: Unexpected templating type error occurred on ({   \n 
>   \"graph\": \"{{  docker_home }}\",\n  \"insecure-registries\" : {{
>   registries | map(attribute='host') | to_json }}\n}): Object of type
>   'generator' is not JSON serializable"}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`map` returns a particular object type which is not a list. You need to transform that to a list before you feed it to `to_json` with the `list` filter

```
{ 
  "insecure-registries": {{ registries | map(attribute='host') | list | to_json }}
}
```